# The value of 'K' the position to insert changes to 0 after shifting value in array

Tags: arrays, c, buffer-overflow

In an array insertion program using C, while shifting the values from one position in the array to another the value of 'k' becomes zero.
I use windows 10, code blocks and also tried it directly with MinGw gcc and still got the same error

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a[6] = {100,200,300,400,500};
    int item = 600, n = 5;
    int i = 0, j = 5, k = 3;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("\nArray = a[%d] = %d", i, a[i]);
    }
    n = n + 1;
    printf("\nThe position value before loop: %d", k);
    while (j >= k) {
        printf("\nThe position value in (%d) loop: %d", j, k);
        a[j + 1] = a[j];
        j = j - 1;
    }
    printf("\nThe position value after loop: %d", k);
    a[k] = item;

    printf("\nThe array after inserting\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("\nList = a[%d] = %d", i, a[i]);
    }

}
```

The output I got:

```
Array = a[1] = 200
Array = a[2] = 300
Array = a[3] = 400
Array = a[4] = 500
The position value before loop: 3
The position value in (5) loop: 3
The position value in (4) loop: 0
The position value in (3) loop: 0
The position value in (2) loop: 0
The position value in (1) loop: 0
The position value in (0) loop: 0
The position value after loop: 0
The array after inserting

List = a[0] = 600
List = a[1] = 100
List = a[2] = 200
List = a[3] = 300
List = a[4] = 400
List = a[5] = 500
```

However it works fine and gives the correct output if I set the size of the array 'a' to '7'.
I got an answer that this was a buffer overflow, but I still don't understand why that happened.

I tried to set the initialization of 'k' before the array initialization and program gave an output of

```
Array = a[0] = 100
Array = a[1] = 200
Array = a[2] = 300
Array = a[3] = 400
Array = a[4] = 500
The position value before loop: 3
The position value in (5) loop: 3
The position value in (4) loop: 3
The position value in (3) loop: 3
The position value after loop: 3
The array after inserting
```

Comment: `a[j + 1] = a[j];` when `j == 5` is out of bounds: https://godbolt.org/z/rnKE37WEb

Comment: Unrelated, but please make it a habit to use *trailing* newline in your output, not leading. Because `stdout` (which is where `printf` writes) is *line* buffered is connected to a terminal, the newline will flush (actually output) the text. With a leading newline you print the *previous* output, not the current. It will also make sure the output of your program ends with a newline, which would make sure the terminal/shell prompt end up on its own line rather than as part of the last line of output from your program.

Comment: @Some programmer dude I will follow that from now on...

Answer (score 0):

When you do `a[j + 1] = a[j];` for the first time, you try to access a[6] (j = 5) and this causes the buffer overflow. You have to keep in mind that the first element of the array is a[0] and the last one you can access is a[5]. Trying to access any position greater or equal to 6 (the array declared size) in the array causes the buffer overflow beacuse there is not enough memory allocated.

One fix is to do `a[j] = a[j - 1];` and declare `j = 5`.
Oher fix is to do `a[j + 1] = a[j];` and declare `j = 4`.